# how to expand the textbox width on wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to expand the width of a input textbox during onclick.

For example, if the input has a default width of 100px, when the user clicks in it to type, it will expand to like 150px in width.

Is it possible to do this in a windows phone 7 application?
My TextBox is named as **"SearchTextBox"**.

Thanks in advance for your hard work.

Comment: Like the stackoverflow has it. See the top center right search box, if  we click on it, it will automatically expands to some width.

Comment: This isn't a full solution, but should get you started: do some research into XAML styles and State transitions. It is possible to have animations triggered by state transitions. I don't have time to dig up all the details and examples but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the `AcceptReturn` property of the textbox to true.

EDIT: My mistake, I meant AcceptReturn, When you press the return key does teh cursor move down?

Comment: There are no option called AllowReturn. I think you have confused. There are two options, AcceptReturn and AllowDrop.If i used AcceptReturn, nothing happened. If i used AllowDrop, it throws an error. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, from XAML, check the properties of the textbox `textwapping` or `allowdrop` and set them as you want.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: AllowDrop is definitely NOT your solution.